# Closing an open ssh port in Linux with one line

Tags: linux

I often ssh tunnel into Rstudio on a server I have set up. I'm trying to devise a single command that I can use to close the ssh port. I know that I can find the PID for localhost:1234 with:

```
sudo lsof -i :1234
```

And I also know that I can kill the process with:

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:1234)
```

The issue is that if I have Chrome open to run Rstudio server, the 2nd command will kill the open Chrome browswer as well. Is there a way to modify the 2nd command so that I close the open ssh port, but not the Chrome browser? There are two PID numbers, so I could theoretically grep for 'ssh' but I'm not sure how.

EDIT FOR CLARITY:

For example, I get the following output from the first command. I want to modify the 2nd command so that I can kill PID 15834, but not 30117. Apologies, I hope that makes more sense.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what Chrome or RStudio has to do with closing an instance of SSH client. You should probably explain things some more.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it to give a better idea of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:1234 -c ssh)
```

> -c => selects  the listing of files for processes executing the command that begins with the characters of c.

Comment: Thanks, this is great!

Answer (score 0):

Just firewall the port:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DROP
```